# Django forms(comments) issue

Tags: django, forms, view, blogs

Why is it that when editing a comment, no matter which comment I try to edit, the last one added always changes?

This is my update view:

```
class CommentUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = BlogComment
    form_class = CommentUpdateForm
    template_name = 'talesoflnk/blog_comment_update_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CommentUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['blog'] = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.blog = blog 
        return super(CommentUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk'],})
    
    def test_func(self):
        comment = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == comment.author:
            return True
        return False
```

Path:

```
path('blog/<int:pk>/comment/update', views.CommentUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_comment')
```

And the form itself:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p>Post your comment for: <a href="{% url 'blog-detail' blog.pk %}">{{blog.name}}</a></p>

<div class="comment-form">
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{form.as_table}}
        </table>
        <input type="submit", value="Save changes">
    </form>
</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

I've no idea what to do to be honest. I was trying to add `<int:comment_pk>` to my route path. But it doesn't work.

Comment: That's because you use an `UpdateView`.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an `UpdateView`, hence it aims to *update* a comment with that id, so if there is a coincidence with the blog id, and a comment id, that comment is modified, which is likely not a good idea.

You can use a `CreateView` that uses the `pk` as `blog_id`:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView


class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = BlogComment
    form_class = CommentUpdateForm
    template_name = 'talesoflnk/blog_comment_update_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(
            **kwargs, blog=get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        )

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.blog_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
```

---

> **Note**: Since [**PEP-3135** <sup>[pep]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/), you don't need to call `super(…)` with parameters if the first parameter is the class in which you define the method, and the second is the first parameter (usually `self`) of the function.